# Very Simple Arduino Update SQL Entry

Tags: mysql, arduino

I have a very simple Arduino project that I am struggling with.
I would like to update a entry in MySQL using Arduino with a Ethernet shield. I am using WAMP for the MySQL server.  Ultimately i would like to post temperature readings to the mysql server every 5 minutes but that is not my concern at the moment. I am not a veteran with Arduino or MySQL, so i thought id ask the Pro's.

WAMP IP Address: 192.168.0.89
Arduino IP Address: 192.168.0.177

The MySQL Database.
Database Username: "root"
Database Password: ""
Database Name: "wordpress"
Database Table: "readings"
Table Field to Update: "voltage1"
The query:

> "UPDATE readings SET voltage1='12v' WHERE device_id=T1;"

The Arduino Sketch:
(Obtained from:  https://launchpad.net/mysql-arduino)

```
#include "SPI.h"
#include "Ethernet.h"
#include "sha1.h"
#include "mysql.h"

byte mac_addr[] = { 0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0F, 0x69, 0xAC };
byte ip_addr[] = { 192, 168, 0, 177 };
byte dns_addr[] = { 192, 168, 0, 37 };
byte gateway_addr[] = { 192, 168, 0, 37 };
byte netmask[] = { 255, 255, 255, 0 };
IPAddress server_addr(192, 168, 0, 89);

Connector my_conn; // The Connector/Arduino reference

char user[] = "root";
char password[] = ""; //the credentials are correct in my code
char INSERT_SQL[] = "UPDATE readings SET voltage1='99' WHERE device_id=T1;";

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
Ethernet.begin(mac_addr, ip_addr, dns_addr, gateway_addr, netmask); //Yes, I know this is way more than necessary, but just to play it safe
delay(1000);
Serial.print("IP: ");
Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP()); // debugging
Serial.println("Connecting...");
if (my_conn.mysql_connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password)) //connect to database
{
delay(500);
my_conn.cmd_query(INSERT_SQL); //Possible problem here, i want to update not insert.
Serial.println("Query Success!");
}
else
Serial.println("Connection failed.");
}

void loop() {
}
```

Serial Monitor:

> IP: 192.168.0.177 
>   Connecting...

It does not ever connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arduino to database connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241550/arduino-to-database-connection)

Comment: I don't understand why we're worrying about the update part when you can't even connect yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you that your SQL is probably wrong.

```
UPDATE readings SET voltage1='12v' WHERE device_id=T1;
```

Should probably be

```
UPDATE readings SET voltage1='12v' WHERE device_id='T1';
```

Sorry I do not know about other problems like the connection.

Regarding

```
//Possible problem here, i want to update not insert.
```

INSERT_SQL is just the name of a variable, you can use BOB as the name and it should still work, rename it to QUERY and relax.

The official example looks similar to your code: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~chuck-bell/mysql-arduino/trunk/view/head:/examples/dht22_sensor_node.cpp

Another thing are you sure the port 3306 is opened on the server?

I believe there is a security measure that prevents everybody but localhost to run mysql commands.

The port should be opened + mysql should allow connection from IPs that are not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: see updated answer with some security measures that might be in place.

Comment: Yep, the port is open.  I will check for any security measures and report back, thank you.

Comment: Who hoo! Mihai you beut!  It connects now.

Comment: now i just need to fix the next error: Error: 29 = No database selected.

Comment: You can just do a UPDATE DBNAME.readings SET voltage1='12v' WHERE device_id='T1';

Comment: It should be a way to select the DB beforehand, but all the examples from the package use the SQLs with the db in them, so just do the same.